# Git Siteground Deployment WordPress Sublime Text

Tags: wordpress, git, deployment, sublimetext3

I am a beginning developer looking to get a great workflow setup before I begin my personal website: kevinbmccall.com

The site has WordPress installed and is hosted by SiteGround.

I enjoy the Sublime Text 3 Editor and am looking to emulate the workflow described here: http://joshuaiz.com/words/the-ultimate-workflow/

I was already in the process of learning Git through the terminal and had a GitHub repo setup through a local project folder. So I didn't really follow Joshua exactly and may have been what led me to get stuck but I think I got to the SSH part.

Here is what I have done so far:

- Installed Sublime Text 3 with SublimeGit Package
- Installed Wordpress on kevinbmccall.com
- Deleted all files from local projects/kevinbmccall folder with git
- Copied all files from siteground server to local folder
- Added and Committed all of these changes to [github repo](https://github.com/kmccallsdsu/kevinbmccall)
- Tried Adding PHP Script to siteground server and setting up webhook

**Issue:** "I want the server to sync with my github repo so I can easily deploy to my live site every time I push to github"

Here is what I can do now:

I can make local changes to my project folder, add them and commit them no problem.

This correctly updates my github repo fine but does not seem to deploy yet.

If I make a change to my local folder, add, commit and check the status it will tell me of an origin/master that is behind in commits and recommends a push

I can push and even see some sort of request triggered because of that attempt at a PHP script I think but I was hoping to see the test txt files show up on the server and they did not.

My Thoughts:

I think my issue has to do with writing to the server and maybe the SSH setup through Siteground. I generated a key but never really used it and all of the online material from siteground points to their SG-Git tool in the c-panel. This requires a more expensive monthly plan and I am just a beginning developer trying to get a personal site up. I am sure the deployment can be accomplished without this upgrade.

Thank you to whomever replies. My goal is to learn as much as possible so I am even more interested in the explanation than the solution.

Comment: Not sure if this screenshot means anything but it is a look at the successful delivery request when i click on the webhook setup in github pointing to a php file mimicking the code in Joshua's link. I don't have the reputation points to post images or more than 2 links...http://kevinbmccall.com/wp-admin/images/screen-shot-delivery-request-success-deployment-issue.png

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, maybe you need [GitHub Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/).

This is a [demo](https://jonathanstark.com/blog/deploying-code-automatically-with-github-webhooks)

```
// Init vars
$LOCAL_ROOT         = "/var/www/my_new_site";
$LOCAL_REPO_NAME    = "public_html";
$LOCAL_REPO         = "{$LOCAL_ROOT}/{$LOCAL_REPO_NAME}";
$REMOTE_REPO        = "git@github.com:jonathanstark/my_new_site.git";
$DESIRED_BRANCH     = "dev";

// Delete local repo if it exists
if (file_exists($LOCAL_REPO)) {
    shell_exec("rm -rf {$LOCAL_REPO}");
}

// Clone fresh repo from github using desired local repo name and checkout the desired branch
echo shell_exec("cd {$LOCAL_ROOT} && git clone {$REMOTE_REPO} {$LOCAL_REPO_NAME} && cd {$LOCAL_REPO} && git checkout {$BRANCH}");

die("done " . mktime());
```